# How do I call a method which has Graphics g as its parameters?

Tags: java, swing, methods, graphics, jpanel

So I am making a game and after someone wins, I want a method to run which displays "x has won" or "y has won". Now my problem is that if I make method to draw a string containing a victory message, then my IDE doesn't allow me to as I can't run a method with Graphics g as the parameters apparently.

Is there any other way to display a message on a JFrame screen?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;`  
//nothing wrong here :P  
public class Demonstration extends JFrame {
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;
    public Demonstration () {
        //My constructor
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        add(panel);
        handler h = new handler();
        b1 = new JButton("yes");
        b2 = new JButton("no");
        //A sub - class to handle events. Created below
        b1.setBounds(34, 34, 34, 34);
        //random
        panel.add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(h);
        b2.setBounds(56, 56, 56, 56);
        // random again
        panel.add(b2);
        b2.addActionListener(h);
        setTitle("Demonstration");
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setSize(720, 720);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

That was my Panel.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
     new Demonstration();
}
```

So let us say I made the handler class later on and I want it to run a piece of code which has an if / else for which button was clicked (.getSource()) and I want to use Graphics to redesign the interface and print out victory messages, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any other way to display a message on a JFrame screen?

Don't try to do custom painting.

I would use a `JOptionPane`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Make Dialogs for more information.

You would use the simple `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can run methods that take a `Graphics` as a parameter.  Any Swing application does so.  You can do it manually, too, though in that case the question is typically how to get the right `Graphics` instance for drawing where you want to draw.

Sometimes what you want to do is extend some `JComponent` (often `JPanel`) and override its `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  The `Graphics` object received by that method is appropriate for drawing on that component.  You then make sure an instance of that component is among the components managed by one of the application's top-level windows.

Alternatively, sometimes it may be suitable to change the *data* in a different component, such as the text of a `JLabel` or `JButton`, or the contents of a `JTextArea`.

Consider also that for displaying an announcement message of some flavor, a popup dialog might be suitable.  There are various ways to construct and diaplay such a dialog, but `JOptionPane` provides some shortcuts that might be useful to you.